# Java catching exceptions and subclases

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throw

Hello,

In Java if a method like `BufferedReader.read()` says it can throw an `IOException` and I try to catch a `FileNotFoundException` and an `IOException` in two catch blocks, what catch blocks will be entered if the file doesn't exist?

Does it enter only the most specific or both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first coded catch that matches the exception will be entered.
**Edited** to incorporate comment from Azodius

For example:

```
try {
   bufferedReader.read();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   // FileNotFoundException handled here
} catch (IOException e) {
   // Other IOExceptions handled here
}
```

This following code does not compile:

```
try {
   bufferedReader.read();
} catch (IOException e) {
   // All IOExceptions (and of course subclasses of IOException) handled here
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   // Would never enter this block, because FileNotFoundException is a IOException
}
```

Compiler message says:

> Unreachable catch block for FileNotFoundException. It is already handled by the catch block for IOException

Comment: @Azodious Oops - yes. It is a compiler error. Thanks I'll note that in answer

Answer (score 2):

Only the first catch block encountered where the exception type of the catch block matches the type of the exception being thrown will be run (more specifically, the first catch block where `(e instaceof <exception type>)==true` will be run).  None of the other catch blocks will be run.

For example

```
try{
    BufferedReader.read();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");}
catch(IOException e){System.out.println("IOException");}
```

Will print `FileNotFoundException` if `BufferedReader.read()` throws a `FileNotFoundException`.

Note that the following doesn't actually compile:

```
try{
    BufferedReader.read();
}
catch(IOException e){System.out.println("IOException");}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");}
```

because Java realizes that it is not possible for the `FileNotFoundException` to be caught because all `FileNotFoundException`s are also `IOException`s.

Answer (score 1):

The first one which is suitable for that type of exception (and only that). So if you `catch` the two exception types above in the order you list them, a `FileNotFoundException` will be caught.

Answer (score 0):

Specific exception is caught first. and it's a compile time error if generic exception is caught befor specific one.